# Create every 30 min a backup of GCP Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google Cloud Platform and I want to make a backup every 30 min. So far I found an out of the box solution within the overview page of the sql instance where I can select a backup window as shown below:

[image]

And next to that I can select the amount of backups to retain, as shown below:

[image]

A backup will be created, but I don't see the possibility to create it based on a strict schedule such as every hour or every 30 min etc. Any idea if that is possible and if it is possible any suggestion how to implement it?

Comment: Google Cloud SQL supports Point-in-time recovery to support rollbacks to any point in time. That option is in your screenshot. There are many types of backups. Your question does not specify your recovery method and respective RPO and RTO objectives.

Comment: The idea was to restore to the latest state of when it was working again if something happens to it. The project requirement is to have a backup every 30 min, but it looks like the point in time recovery is enough to recover the database when something went wrong, right? But any idea if point-in-time recovery can be restored to any time or is it just a snapshot at a random moment?

Comment: Read the documentation for Point-in-time so that you understand the feature and what recovery it offers. As I mentioned in my comment "rollbacks to any point in time".

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do this using this web console UI.
The approach I would take, is to use Cloud Scheduler to trigger a cloud function every 30 mins that will trigger the SQL backup.

That would mean developing a small python script or other language for the Cloud Function. It would only be a few lines though. If you need a primer on how to connect to Cloud SQL using Cloud Functions, this looks like it would be useful: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/connecting-to-cloud-sql-with-cloud-functions#0